# MySQL: How can where clause be invalid for delete statement but work fine for select statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run a delete statement in mysql - I get an error.  To test I tried running it as "select *" instead of "delete".  Nothing else changed, and it runs fine.  Any idea why?

here is the full delete statement

```
DELETE
from timeclock_raw tr
where tr.rectype = 'active'
      and tr.recdate > '2018-08-17'
      and tr.seconds < (select max(tr1.seconds) as secs
                        from timeclock_raw tr1
                        where tr1.env = tr.env and tr1.intid = tr.intid and tr1.studycode = tr.studycode and tr1.recdate = tr.recdate)
      and tr.seconds > (select min(tr2.seconds) as secs
                        from timeclock_raw tr2
                        where tr2.env = tr.env and tr2.intid = tr.intid and tr2.studycode = tr.studycode and tr2.recdate = tr.recdate);
```

I get this error

```
[2018-08-19 20:46:51] [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'tr
[2018-08-19 20:46:51] where tr.rectype = 'active'
[2018-08-19 20:46:51] and tr.recdate > '2018-08-17'
[2018-08-19 20:46:51] and tr.' at line 2
```

but this runs fine...

```
select *
from timeclock_raw tr
where tr.rectype = 'active'
      and tr.recdate > '2018-08-17'
      and tr.seconds < (select max(tr1.seconds) as secs
                        from timeclock_raw tr1
                        where tr1.env = tr.env and tr1.intid = tr.intid and tr1.studycode = tr.studycode and tr1.recdate = tr.recdate)
      and tr.seconds > (select min(tr2.seconds) as secs
                        from timeclock_raw tr2
                        where tr2.env = tr.env and tr2.intid = tr.intid and tr2.studycode = tr.studycode and tr2.recdate = tr.recdate);
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: based on first response I tried this but got another error... any ideas?

```
sql> delete tr
from timeclock_raw tr
where tr.rectype = 'active'
      and datediff(now(),tr.recdate) < 3
      and tr.seconds < (select max(tr1.seconds) as secs
                        from timeclock_raw tr1
                        where tr1.env = tr.env and tr1.intid = tr.intid and tr1.studycode = tr.studycode and tr1.recdate = tr.recdate)
      and tr.seconds > (select min(tr2.seconds) as secs
                        from timeclock_raw tr2
                        where tr2.env = tr.env and tr2.intid = tr.intid and tr2.studycode = tr.studycode and tr2.recdate = tr.recdate)
[2018-08-20 01:07:24] [HY000][1093] You can't specify target table 'tr' for update in FROM clause
[2018-08-20 01:07:24] [HY000][1093] You can't specify target table 'tr' for update in FROM clause
```

Comment: I thought we don't need `from` in the `delete` statement, it's just `DELETE table_name WHERE...`, no?

Comment: docs says 'If you declare an alias for a table, you must use the alias when referring to the table' [see](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html), then only put the alias before `from` or dont use it

Comment: @JohnLaw From MySQL Documentation, the `FROM` is still required: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html

Comment: @JohnStark ah ok, new syntax for me to learn then. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not allow you to use the table being deleted (or updated) in the rest of the query.  The normal solution is to use `join`s:

```
delete tr
from timeclock_raw tr join
     (select tr1.env, tr1.intid, tr1.studycode, tr1.recdate, min(tr1.seconds) as minsecs, max(tr1.seconds) as maxsecs
      from timeclock_raw tr1
      group by tr1.env, tr1.intid, tr1.studycode, tr1.recdate
     ) x
     on tr1.env = tr.env and
        tr1.intid = tr.intid and
        tr1.studycode = tr.studycode and
        tr1.recdate = tr.recdate
where tr.rectype = 'active' and
      tr.recdate > '2018-08-17' and
      tr.seconds < x.maxsecs and
      tr.seconds > x.minsecs;
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is perfect - one small tweak.
in the following section all the "tr1." should be "x.".  Other than that, this seems to be doing exactly what I want.  Thanks so much!  

     on tr1.env = tr.env and
        tr1.intid = tr.intid and
        tr1.studycode = tr.studycode and
        tr1.recdate = tr.recdate

Answer (score 2):

The error is not complaining about the `WHERE` clause, it is complaining about the use of a table alias that was not previously declared before the `FROM`. You need to rewrite the query as

```
DELETE tr FROM timeclock_raw tr WHERE ...
```

Check out the very end of the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html) page.

Comment: Thanks!! I am used to DB2 syntax... I need to get more familiar with MySQL. You are a life saver!

Comment: @Nick . . . Although that is one problem with the query, I would not consider that to be the main issue.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Indeed, I was just answering OPs question as posted.

Comment: @nick . . . This is only one problem with the query.  I don't object to your answer (which correctly identifies one issue), just the upvotes.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Fair enough but I can't do anything about them short of deleting the answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can you help me out with what the main issue is?  I tried this suggestions but I just wind up with... (to long to put here - I will add to the bottom of the question)

Comment: Hi Ben, sorry I wasn't able to help you with the whole problem; I apologise - I didn't look closely enough at your query to realise there was a second issue. By the time I came back to the question @GordonLinoff had already posted an answer dealing with that so I'm glad you got it sorted in the end.